# How to read value from appsettings in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can use a value from appsetting.json file in Jquery.

Actually I want to add no. of days to my initial starting date. so I have stored a pre-defined duration of day in appsettings.

Appsettings.json

```
 "SubscriptionDuration": {
    "subscriptionDays" : 365
  }
```

JQuery File:

```
//This to set default startDate as todays
document.getElementById("subscriptionDate").valueAsDate = new Date();
```

Can anyone please help me to get the value from Appsettings file. Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can use ```jQuery.getJSON()``` function. plz read more here, https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: You can't read directly from appsettings.json using jQuery. You would need to either make an AJAX request to an endpoint in your C# code which retrieves the value from appsettings and returns it,. Better still if you're going to use AJAX, generate the data server side and return that to your jQuery code.

Comment: @AsiqurRahman you can't directly read from appsettings.json using an AJAX request - it's a protected file.